Unitarity in black hole final-state projection
Horowitz-Maldacena model, which proposes a resolution to the black hole information paradox by introducing a final-state boundary condition at the black hole singularity. From what I understand, the model uses quantum teleportation principles to suggest that the information from collapsing matter is preserved in a unitary process.
Could someone explain in detail how the final-state projection works to ensure unitarity? Specifically, how does this projection interact with the outgoing Hawking radiation, and what are the mathematical implications for the entanglement structure across the event horizon?

Any reference to a singularity in an evaporating black hole is absurd. In a star collapse, the singularity does not form in a finite cosmological time.

@safesphere Could you please explain in a little more detail?

Due to the diverging time dilation at the horizon, nothing can get there until the infinite cosmological time, including the original matter of the collapsing star. From there, the radial direction is timelike, meaning the horizon opens a temporal shrinking tunnel briefly beyond the infinite future of the universe. The Schwarzschild singularity is the last moment of time at the end of this tunnel. However, if a black hole evaporates and disappears, it happens in a finite time. Hence the event horizon never forms and the singularity does not happen. Draw constant time lines on Penrose diagrams.
